# Carbon date x day of the y week in next month i.e. 4th monday

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I'd like to add get the x'th day of the y'th week in next month, i.e. the 4th monday of the next month (or arbitrary months away).

I can generate where I am at the moment with something like

```
$day = $date->dayOfWeek;
$week = $date->weekOfMonth;
```

But I am struggling to work out how to manipulate `$date` to get where I want to.  The alternative is to use PHP's relative formarts http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php
but I'd rather stick to Carbon if I can.

Another possiblity is to go to the first of the month with

```
$date->addMonth();
$date->day = 1;
```

and then do a loop to find the correct day and then add on weeks but this seems like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
$day = $date->dayOfWeek();
$week = $date->weekOfMonth();

$date->addMonth();
$date->day = 1;    //Move to first of the month

while($date->dayOfWeek != $day)
{
    $date->addDay();    //Cycle through days until we get to correct day of the week
}

$date->addWeeks($week - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
    echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime('next Monday 2012-04-01'));
?>
```